# How can I debug Android applications on my Samsung Galaxy S Advanced on Windows 8?

Tags: android, windows-8, adb

I have a Samsung Galaxy S Advanced that I want to use to test my Android applications on. Just recently, I switched to Windows 8. Everything appeared to be working fine, Windows 8 detected my device fine however, the device was not list when I ran **adb devices**. I know I set-up the phone correctly, enabling USB debugging in the developer settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can be fixed by installing the official **Samsung USB Mobile Phone driver**. You can find this driver at the official Samsung site: http://www.samsung.com/nl/support/model/GT-I9100LKATNL-downloads After installing this driver, your device will show up in **adb devices**

Comment: if you knew the answer.. what's the reason of asking?

Comment: To share my solution with others, so others know how to solve this problem when they encounter it. It is even accepted SO etiquette. See Jeff Atwood's post in: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question#_=_